# Sphinx class attribute documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I've been trying to document my [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/) based application, but I'm having problems with documenting attributes on my Document classes.

I have taken the correct syntax for doing so is the following:

```
class Asset(Document):
     #: This is the URI of the document
     uri = StringField()
```

I've tried every way of documenting these attributes that I've found and even added an attribute that isn't a MongoEngine field just to make sure this isn't the issue:

```
class Asset(Document):
    """
    The representation of a file uploaded into the data store.
    """

    #: This is a test attribute.
    foo = 'bar'
    """baz?"""

    #: This is a URI.
    uri = StringField(required=True)
    """This is a URI """
```

I have tried out various combinations of directives in the corresponding `.rst` file. At the moment it looks like this:

```
.. currentmodule:: mymodule.asset
.. autoclass:: Asset
.. autoattribute:: Asset.foo
.. autoattribute:: Asset.uri
```

The output isn't very satisfying: The `foo` attribute has no documentation displayed at all and the uri field has MongoEngine's "A unicode string field." (the documentation of the `StringField` class) as documentation. Also the attribute documentation is not put "under" the class (as with automodule + :members: - which outputs all fields with their MongoEngine description)

Do I miss a Sphinx Extension? Or am I screwing up the Syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this problem was caused, in addition to mzjn's answer by something else: I had to fully qualify the class I was `..autoclass::`ing for it to work because the module I specified for `..currentmodule::` was importing used the `from x import y` syntax, i.e. the following syntax works:

```
.. currentmodule: mymodule.asset
.. autoclass: mymodule.asset.Asset
   :members:
```

Long story short: **Check your imports!**

Answer (score 12):

To get the members of a class into the documentation, use the `:members:` option:

```
.. autoclass:: Asset
   :members:
```

Without `:members:`, [only the class docstring](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autoclass) is inserted.

See also the [`autodoc_default_flags`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_flags) configuration option.

---

You can get the same result as above with `autoattribute` and without `:members:` (note the indentation):

```
.. autoclass:: Asset

   .. autoattribute:: foo
   .. autoattribute:: uri
```

---

I cannot reproduce the problem that the `uri` attribute gets documented using the docstring from StringField.

I'm using Sphinx 1.2.2.

Comment: Hi, this was part of the problem, I've added an own answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23086206/660848) which fixed the issue and also made the "sphinx.ext.viewcode" extension work. Hooray! :)